# How to detect and remove indentation of a piped text

Tags: bash, unix, pipe

I'm looking for a way to remove the indentation of a piped text. Below is a solution using `cut -c 9-` which assumes the indentation is 8 character wide.

I'm looking for a solution which can detect the number of spaces to remove. This implies going through the whole (piped) file to know the minimum number of spaces (tabs?) used to indent it, then remove them on each line.

#### run.sh

```
help() {
    awk '
    /esac/{b=0}
    b
    /case "\$arg" in/{b=1}' \
    "$me" \
    | cut -c 9-
}

while [[ $# -ge 1 ]]
do
    arg="$1"
    shift
    case "$arg" in
        help|h|?|--help|-h|'-?')
            # Show this help
            help;;
    esac
done
```

`$ ./run.sh --help`

```
help|h|?|--help|-h|'-?')
    # Show this help
    help;;
```

---

Note: `echo $'    4\n  2\n   3' | python3 -c 'import sys; import textwrap as tw; print(tw.dedent(sys.stdin.read()), end="")'` works but I expect there is a better, way (I mean, one which doesn't only depends on software more common than python. Maybe awk? I wouldn't mind seeing a perl solution either.

Note2: `echo $'    4\n  2\n   3' | python -c 'import sys; import textwrap as tw; print tw.dedent(sys.stdin.read()),'` also works (Python 2.7.15rc1).

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: The question is unclear, the objective of what you're trying to do in help() is not obvious.  What possible inputs will you see?  If you just want to remove leading spaces, something like `| sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]+//'` should work.

Comment: @JeffBreadner: I suggest to replace `-e` with `-E` or replace `+` with `\+`.

Comment: @Cyrus:  Right you are, thanks!  I should really test before posting.

Comment: Do you care about handling of tabs, or are we just counting number of bytes of whitespace here?

Comment: Aside: Something that can be read to resolve to "please implement X in as many languages as possible" is generally frowned  on here. Questions should be *specific*, [about *actual problems you face*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and absolutely not open-ended. Once you have an implementation that meets your needs, you no longer face an actual problem. Wanting to drop the Python dependency to run with only baseline UNIX tools (like awk, so dawg's answer is a good one) is a fair "actual problem". Wanting to see more alternative implementations out of curiosity is not.

Comment: Can you name a modern Unix-y system where Python is not available? Why do you think Python is uncommon?

Answer (score 4):

The following is pure bash, with no external tools or command substitutions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
all_lines=( )
min_spaces=9999 # start with something arbitrarily high
while IFS= read -r line; do
  all_lines+=( "$line" )
  if [[ ${line:0:$min_spaces} =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]]; then
    continue  # this line has at least as much whitespace as those preceding it
  fi
  # this line has *less* whitespace than those preceding it; we need to know how much.
  [[ $line =~ ^([[:space:]]*) ]]
  line_whitespace=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  min_spaces=${#line_whitespace}
done

for line in "${all_lines[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\n' "${line:$min_spaces}"
done
```

Its output is:

```
  4
2
 3
```

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have:

```
$ echo $'    4\n  2\n   3\n\ttab'
    4
  2
   3
    tab
```

You can use the Unix [expand](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/expand.html) utility to expand the tabs to spaces. Then run through an `awk` to count the minimum number of spaces on a line:

```
$ echo $'    4\n  2\n   3\n\ttab' | 
expand | 
awk 'BEGIN{min_indent=9999999}
     {lines[++cnt]=$0
      match($0, /^[ ]*/)
      if(RLENGTH<min_indent) min_indent=RLENGTH
     }
     END{for (i=1;i<=cnt;i++) 
               print substr(lines[i], min_indent+1)}'
  4
2
 3
      tab
```

Comment: Note: SO kinda screws up the `\t` in this post. It is actually a tab that then is converted to 8 spaces by `expand` and then the awk reduces that to 6 spaces...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the (semi-) obvious temp file solution.

```
#!/bin/sh

t=$(mktemp -t dedent.XXXXXXXXXX) || exit
trap 'rm -f $t' EXIT ERR
awk '{ n = match($0, /[^ ]/); if (NR == 1 || n<min) min = n }1
    END { exit min+1 }' >"$t"
cut -c $?- "$t"
```

This obviously fails if all lines have more than 255 leading whitespace characters because then the result won't fit into the exit code from Awk.

This has the advantage that we are not restricting ourselves to the available memory. Instead, we are restricting ourselves to the available disk space.  The drawback is that disk *might* be slower, but the advantage of not reading big files into memory will IMHO trump that.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `< "$t"` instead of  `> "$t"`? Also there is a `1` sitting at the end of the first awk line, shouldn't it be removed? Also, as per my answer, it should be possible to replace `; if (NR == 1 || n<min)` by `} NR == 1 || n<min {`.

Comment: No, we are reading standard input and printing the results into the temporary file, which will still be empty at this point. The `1` is a common Awk idiom for "print everything".

Comment: I see no reason to move the `if` to a separate block though you are correct that it would be semantically identical.

Comment: You can get rid of the 255 character limitation by `cat > "$t"`, then `awk '... END {print min + 1}' < "$t" | read c`

Comment: What about `tee` then?

Comment: It's still reading the file three times, but it would be more elegant than `cat`, yes.  If you genuinely need to handle files with indentation of more than 255 characters on all lines, something else is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $'    4\n  2\n   3\n  \n   more spaces in  the    line\n  ...' | \
(text="$(cat)"; echo "$text" \
| cut -c "$(echo "$text" | sed 's/[^ ].*$//' | awk 'NR == 1 {a = length} length < a {a = length} END {print a + 1}')-"\
)
```

With explanations:

```
echo $'    4\n  2\n   3\n  \n   more spaces in  the    line\n  ...' | \
(
    text="$(cat)" # Obtain the input in a varibale
    echo "$text" | cut -c "$(
        # `cut` removes the n-1 first characters of each line of the input, where n is:
            echo "$text" | \
            sed 's/[^ ].*$//' | \
            awk 'NR == 1 || length < a {a = length} END {print a + 1}'
            # sed: keep only the initial spaces, remove the rest
            # awk:
            # At the first line `NR == 1`, get the length of the line `a = length`.
            # For any shorter line `a < length`, update the length `a = length`.
            # At the end of the piped input, print the shortest length + 1.
            # ... we add 1 because in `cut`, characters of the line are indexed at 1.
        )-"
)
```

---

Update:

It is possible to avoid spawning `sed`. As per tripleee's comment, sed's `s///` can be replace awk's `sub()`. Here is an even shorter option, using `n = match()` as in tripleee's answer.

```
echo $'    4\n  2\n   3\n  \n   more spaces in  the    line\n  ...' | \
(
    text="$(cat)" # Obtain the input in a varibale
    echo "$text" | cut -c "$(
        # `cut` removes the a-1 first characters of each line of the input, where a is:
            echo "$text" | \
            awk '
                {n = match($0, /[^ ]/)}
                NR == 1 || n < a {a = n}
                END || a == 0 {print a + 1; exit 0}'
            # awk:
            # At every line, get the position of the first non-space character
            # At the first line `NR == 1`, copy that lenght to `a`.
            # For any line with less spaces than `a` (`n < a`) update `a`, (`a = n`).
            # At the end of the piped input, print a + 1.
            # a is then the minimum number of common leading spaces found in all lines.
            # ... we add 1 because in `cut`, characters of the line are indexed at 1.
            #
            # I'm not sure the whether the `a == 0 {...;  exit 0}` optimisation will let the "$text" be written to the script stdout yet (which is not desirable at all). Gotta test that when I get the time.

        )-"
)
```

Apparently, it's also possible to do in Perl 6 with the function `my &f = *.indent(*);`.

Comment: The `sed` snippet can be refactored into the Awk script; it's a simple `sub()` though it's probably more efficient to simply find the index of the first non-space character directly.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `awk`, based on [dawg’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54029048/1661012). Major differences include:

- No need to set an arbitrary large number for indentation, which feels hacky.
- Works on text with empty lines, by not considering them when gathering the lowest indented line.

```
awk '
  {
    lines[++count] = $0
    if (NF == 0) next
    match($0, /[^ ]/)
    if (length(min) == 0 || RSTART < min) min = RSTART
  }
  END {
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) print substr(lines[i], min)
  }
' <<< $'    4\n  2\n   3'
```

Or all on the same line

```
awk '{ lines[++count] = $0; if (NF == 0) next; match($0, /[^ ]/); if (length(min) == 0 || RSTART < min) min = RSTART; } END { for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) print substr(lines[i], min) }' <<< $'    4\n  2\n   3'
```

Explanation:

Add current line to an array, and increment `count` variable

```
{
  lines[++count] = $0
```

If line is empty, skip to next iteration

```
  if (NF == 0) next
```

Set `RSTART` to the start index of the first non-space character.

```
  match($0, /[^ ]/)
```

If `min` isn’t set or is higher than RSTART, set the former to the latter.

```
  if (length(min) == 0 || RSTART < min) min = RSTART
}
```

Run after all input is read.

```
END {
```

Loop over the array, and for each line print only a substring going from the index set in `min` to the end of the line.

```
  for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) print substr(lines[i], min)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

##### solution using bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cb=$(xclip -selection clipboard -o)
firstchar=${cb::1}
if [ "$firstchar" == $'\t' ];then
  tocut=$(echo "$cb" | awk -F$'\t' '{print NF-1;}' | sort -n | head -n1)
else
  tocut=$(echo "$cb" | awk -F '[^ ].*' '{print length($1)}' | sort -n | head -n1)
fi

echo "$cb" | cut -c$((tocut+1))- | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Note: assumes first line has the left-most indent

Works for both spaces and tabs

Ctrl+V some text, run that bash script, and now the dedented text is saved to your clipboard

##### solution using python

detab.py

```py
import sys
import textwrap

data = sys.stdin.readlines()
data = "".join(data)
print(textwrap.dedent(data))
```

use with pipes

```
xclip -selection clipboard -o | python detab.py | xclip -selection clipboard
```